# Different Results When Using the ThreadStatic Attribute

Tags: c#

I tried running a code that uses a ThreadStatic attribute and for some reason different results are being displayed.

```
[ThreadStatic]
    public static int _field;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                _field++;
                Console.WriteLine("Thread A: {0}", _field);
            }
        }).Start();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                _field++;
                Console.WriteLine("Thread B: {0}", _field);
            }
        }).Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Result 1:
[image: Result 1]

Result 2:
[image: Result 2]

Can anyone explain to me why? Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  How do the results differ from your expectations?  Both look perfectly acceptable as results for this code.

Comment: The magic of multithreading.  Why would you think it wouldn't be like this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner and am trying to understand the concept of threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute code on multiple threads the order of execution becomes somewhat unpredictable. You might get the exact same result over and over, but then it will do something different.

That inconsistent behavior is fine as long as you don't depend on consistent behavior. Think of it like two people painting a building - one starts on the back and one starts on the front because it's faster and because it's not critical that one finish before the other.

This [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CbBPbE) demonstrates. It puts a bunch of consecutive numbers in a `ConcurrentQueue`, and then uses multiple threads to move them first-in-first-out into another queue. You might expect that they would always arrive in the second queue in the same order, and more often than not they do. But once in a while they don't.

It's very important to be aware of this behavior. Otherwise we can write multithreaded code, we test it and it seems to work one way, then later we get unpredictable results that happen once in a while but we can't figure out why and we can't repeat it when debugging. If that happens then the problem can be very difficult to find. But that's only a problem if we depend on behavior that isn't predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have no control over the timing of when a thread gets a CPU timeslice. So the order will be different for each run.

Comment: Each thread has it's own copy of the variable, so no, they are not interacting with each other at all, and there is no need for them to synchronize access to any resources because they have no shared resource.

Comment: Yeah, just remove everything after the second line. (edit) like you just did :|